# Rails - link_to a specific item#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

Using the Rails model and controller, I have created a few items. Each item has a year (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015). I can access the items#show by using a vanity URL that I defined: example.com/items/2015-item. This works for any year and item.

In the top navigation bar, I have a button that when clicked, I want it to link directly to the 2015-item page. The current link is:

```
    link_to ('items/2015-item')
```

This works when I click it from the home page, but if I am already on the 2015-item page, I get the link: example.com/items/items/2015-item. Obviously it is tacking on the extra items directory, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to define the item_path in routes.rb.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` in your command line and copy the result to your question via an edit?

Comment: I think it should be `link_to ('/items/2015-item')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
link_to('/items/2015-item')
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I completely missed that. Thanks!